# Checking a beta regression model via glmmTMB with DHARMa package

Tags: r, residuals, random-effects-model, glmm, glmmtmb

I would like some clarification whether my model is well specified or not (since I do not have much experience with Beta regression models).

My variable is the percentual of dirth area in the denture. For every pacient, the dentist applied a special product in either left or right side on the denture (leaving the other side as placebo) in order to remove dirth area.

After that, he calculate the total area of each side of the denture, and the total dirth area for each side.

I need to test whether the product is efficient to remove the dirth.

My initial model (prop.bio is the proportion of dirth area):

```
library(glmmTMB)    
m1 <- glmmTMB(prop.bio ~ Product*Side + (1|Pacients), data, family=list(family="beta",link="logit"))
```

**Update:**

My final model after manual backward selection via TRV test (and it is also the main question of the researcher):

```
m1.f <- glmmTMB(prop.bio ~ Product + (1|Pacients), data, family=list(family="beta",link="logit"))
```

My residual diagnosis using `DHARMa`:

```
library(DHARMa)
res = simulateResiduals(m1.f)
plot(res, rank = T)
```

[image]

According to my reading on `DHARMa` vignette, my model could be wrong based on the right plot. What should I do then? (Is my model specification wrong?)

Thanks in advance!

Data:

```
structure(list(Pacients = structure(c(5L, 6L, 2L, 11L, 26L, 29L, 
20L, 24L, 8L, 14L, 19L, 7L, 13L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 11L, 26L, 
29L, 20L, 24L, 8L, 14L, 19L, 7L, 13L, 4L, 3L, 23L, 25L, 12L, 
21L, 10L, 22L, 18L, 27L, 15L, 9L, 17L, 28L, 1L, 16L, 23L, 25L, 
12L, 21L, 10L, 22L, 18L, 27L, 15L, 9L, 17L, 28L, 1L, 16L), .Label = c("Adlf", 
"Alda", "ClrW", "ClsB", "CrCl", "ElnL", "Gema", "Héli", "Inác", 
"Inlv", "InsS", "Ircm", "Ivnr", "Lnld", "Lrds", "LusB", "Mart", 
"Mrnz", "Murl", "NGc1", "NGc2", "Nlcd", "Norc", "Oliv", "Ramr", 
"Slng", "Svrs", "Vldm", "Vlsn"), class = "factor"), Area = c(3942, 
3912, 4270, 4583, 2406, 2652, 2371, 4885, 3704, 3500, 4269, 3743, 
3414, 4231, 3089, 4214, 3612, 4459, 4678, 2810, 2490, 2577, 4264, 
4287, 3487, 4547, 3663, 3199, 3836, 3237, 3846, 4116, 3514, 3616, 
3609, 4053, 3810, 4532, 4380, 4103, 4552, 3745, 3590, 3386, 3998, 
4449, 3367, 3698, 3840, 4457, 3906, 4384, 4000, 4156, 3594, 3258, 
4094, 2796), Side = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Right", "Left"), class = "factor"), Biofilme = c(1747, 
1770, 328, 716, 1447, 540, 759, 1328, 2320, 1718, 1226, 977, 
1193, 2038, 1685, 2018, 1682, 416, 679, 2076, 947, 1423, 1661, 
1618, 1916, 1601, 1833, 1050, 1780, 1643, 1130, 2010, 2152, 812, 
2550, 1058, 826, 1526, 2905, 1299, 2289, 1262, 1965, 3016, 1630, 
1823, 1889, 1319, 2678, 1205, 472, 1694, 2161, 1444, 1062, 819, 
2531, 2310), Product = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), prop.bio = c(0.443176052765094, 
0.452453987730061, 0.0768149882903981, 0.156229543966834, 0.601413133832086, 
0.203619909502262, 0.320118093631379, 0.271852610030706, 0.626349892008639, 
0.490857142857143, 0.287186694776294, 0.261020571733903, 0.349443468072642, 
0.481682817300874, 0.545483975396568, 0.478879924062648, 0.465669988925803, 
0.0932944606413994, 0.145147498931167, 0.738790035587189, 0.380321285140562, 
0.552192471866511, 0.389540337711069, 0.377420107301143, 0.549469457986808, 
0.352100285902793, 0.5004095004095, 0.328227571115974, 0.464025026068822, 
0.507568736484399, 0.293811752470099, 0.488338192419825, 0.612407512805919, 
0.224557522123894, 0.706566916043225, 0.261041204046385, 0.216797900262467, 
0.336716681376876, 0.66324200913242, 0.316597611503778, 0.502855887521968, 
0.3369826435247, 0.547353760445682, 0.890726520968695, 0.407703851925963, 
0.409755001123848, 0.561033561033561, 0.356679286100595, 0.697395833333333, 
0.270361229526587, 0.12083973374296, 0.386405109489051, 0.54025, 
0.347449470644851, 0.295492487479132, 0.251381215469613, 0.618221787982413, 
0.82618025751073)), row.names = c(NA, -58L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr** it's reasonable for you to worry, but having looked at a variety of different graphical diagnostics I don't think everything looks pretty much OK.  My answer will illustrate a bunch of other ways to look at a `glmmTMB` fit - more involved/less convenient than DHARMa, but it's good to look at the fit as many different ways as one can.

First let's look at the raw data (which I've called `dd`):

```
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(dd,aes(Product,prop.bio,colour=Side))+
    geom_line(colour="gray",aes(group=Pacients))+
    geom_point(aes(shape=Side))+
    scale_colour_brewer(palette="Dark2")
```

[image]

My first point is that the right-hand plot made by `DHARMa` (and in general, all predicted-vs-residual plots) is looking for *bias* in the model, i.e. patterns where the residuals have systematic patterns with respect to the mean. **This should never happen** for a model with only categorical predictors (provided it contains all possible interactions of the predictors), because the model has one parameter for every possible fitted value ... we'll see below that it doesn't happen if we look at fitted vs residuals at the population level rather than the individual level ...

The quickest way to get fitted vs residual plots (e.g. analogous to base-R's `plot.lm()` method or `lme4's` `plot.merMod()`) is via `broom.mixed::augment()` + ggplot:

```
library(broom.mixed)
aa <- augment(m1.f, data=dd)
gg2 <- (ggplot(aa, aes(.fitted,.resid))
    + geom_line(aes(group=Pacients),colour="gray")
    + geom_point(aes(colour=Side,shape=Product))
    + geom_smooth()
)
```

[image]

These fitted and residual values are at the individual-patient level. They do show a mild trend (*which I admittedly don't understand at the moment*), but the overall trend doesn't seem large relative to the scatter in the data.

To check that this phenomenon is indeed caused by predictions at the patient rather than the population level, and to test the argument above that population-level effects should have exactly *zero* trend in the fitted vs. residual plot, we can hack the `glmmTMB` predictions to construct population-level predictions and residuals (the next release of `glmmTMB` should make this easier):

```
aa$.fitted0 <- predict(m1.f, newdata=transform(dd,Pacients=NA),type="response")
aa$.resid0 <- dd$prop.bio-aa$.fitted0
gg3 <- (ggplot(aa, aes(.fitted0,.resid0))
    + geom_line(aes(group=Pacients),colour="gray")
    + geom_point(aes(colour=Side,shape=Product))
    + geom_smooth()
)
```

(note that if you run this code, you'll get lots of warnings from `geom_smooth()`, which is unhappy about being run when the predictor variable [i.e., the fitted value] only has two unique levels)

[image]

Now the mean value of the residuals is (almost?) exactly zero for both levels (`Product=="No"` and `Product=="Yes"`).

As long as we're at it, let's check the diagnostics for the random effects:

```
lme4:::dotplot.ranef.mer(ranef(m1.f)$cond)
```

[image]

This looks OK: no sign of discontinuous jumps (indicating possible multi-modality in random effects) or outlier patients.

### other comments

- I disapprove on general principles of reducing the model based on which terms seem to be important (e.g. dropping `Side` from the model after running `anova()`): in general, data-driven model reduction messes up inference.

Comment: _"in general, data-driven model reduction messes up inference."_
+1!

Comment: Tks Ben! I just edited my question saying that I did backward selection via Likelihood ratio test (And in some other problems, I use LASSO/RIDGE). What do you consider being the best approach when I want to simplify my model?

Comment: If you simplify your model based on the response variable, *in any way*, you will make inference much more difficult.  If you're only interested in prediction, and not in interval estimates/confidence intervals/p-values, that doesn't matter.  see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/377527/stepwise-aic-does-there-exist-controversy-surrounding-this-topic/377532#377532 (although there may be better answers floating around on CV)

Answer (score 7):

I am the developer of DHARMa. Dimitris and Ben are correct, the pattern originates from the known issue that glmmTMB does not (yet) allow making predictions based on fixed effects only, which sometimes produces this pattern. I hope we can fix this issue with the next release of glmmTMB, which should allow fixed-effect predictions.

[EDIT Nov 21: this problem was fixed in glmmTMB approximately 1yr ago.]

In your case, it is obvious that the predicted variable in your model is based on fixed and random effects, because your fixed effects have only one categorical predictor, so you should have only 2 values on your x axis. We can produce a plot using only fixed effects as predictors easily by hand:

```
plotResiduals(data$Product, res$scaledResiduals)
```

Which results in a plot that looks fine

[image]

btw, agree with Ben that I would not do model selection based on significance, this is essentially p-hacking. If you start with Product*Side, report this model, unless you think there is a serious issue with the inference.

Comment: Tks Florian! I just edited my question saying that I did backward selection via Likelihood ratio test (And in some other problems, I use LASSO/RIDGE). Is it still wrong? What should I do? I always look forward a solution to simplify the interpretation for the researcher.

Comment: Just stay with the initial model. This doesn't appear to be a case where MS is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the section about **glmmTMB** in the [vignette of **DHARMa**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html#glmmtmb). It seems to be an issue with regard to how predictions are calculated given the random effects.

As an alternative, you may try the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package. You can find examples using the **DHARMa** [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Goodness_of_Fit.html).

Comment: Yes.  I think you should quote this from the message that appears when you run `simulateResiduals()`: "glmmTMB doesn't implement an option to create unconditional predictions from the model, which means that predicted values (in res ~ pred) plots include the random effects. With strong random effects, this can sometimes create diagonal patterns from bottom left to top right in the res ~ pred plot"