# Stepwise model selection by AIC

Tags: regularization, aic, stepwise-regression, time-complexity

I am learning about performing stepwise model selection by AIC and having some questions:

1. What is the regularization parameter for step-AIC?
2. In what way is forward step-AIC an evolution of univariate screening?
   What is the potential problem regarding the computational burden?

Answer (score 1):

*Preamble:* Avoid doing stepwise model selection via AIC if there are plan to use the model for anything else other than prediction. Please see this thread for more details: *[Algorithms for automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection)*. To your side questions:

1. The "regularisation parameter" is number of parameters in the model.
2. It really isn't an evolution; more like a slightly more principled version of it. It is a bit unclear what you mean by "computational burden" but realistically, the actual computational burden is not huge, especially within the context of GLMs where we can warm-start our IRWLS.

Again, avoid using stepwise regression unless there is an *extremely* good reason (e.g. expensive to collect new data for multiple variables, very constrained memory spaces, etc.) and there are not intention to interpret the model causality/statistically/whatever. CV.SE has some excellent threads on the matter, see for starters: *[A more definitive discussion of variable selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223808)*, *[Choosing variables to include in a multiple linear regression model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21265)* and *[Stepwise AIC - Does there exist controversy surrounding this topic?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/377527)*.